# CPU timer internal details

Tags: timer, cpu, clock

A timer is used for CPU protection. What mechanism is the timer used to compute actual current time in the PC?

Answer (score 1):

Almost all modern computers have a built-in real-time clock, which keeps rough track of the time even while the computer is off.  The computer can simply read from the RTC to get the current time.